# Why character streams?

Tags: java, iostream, java-io

I understand that Java character streams wrap byte streams such that the underlying byte stream is interpreted as per the system default or an otherwise specifically defined character set.

My systems default char-set is UTF-8.

If I use a `FileReader` to read in a text file, everything looks normal as the default char-set is used to interpret the bytes from the underlying `InputStreamReader`. If I explicitly define an `InputStreamReader` to read the UTF-8 encoded text file in as UTF-16, everything obviously looks strange. Using a byte stream like `FileInputStream` and redirecting its output to System.out, everything looks fine.

So, my questions are;

- Why is it useful to use a character stream?
- Why would I use a character stream instead of directly using a byte stream?
- When is it useful to define a specific char-set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Code that deals with strings should only "think" in terms of text - for example, reading an input source line by line, you don't want to care about the nature of that source.

However, storage is usually byte-oriented - so you need to create a conversion between the byte-oriented view of a source (encapsulated by `InputStream`) and the character-oriented view of a source (encapsulated by `Reader`).

So a method which (say) counts the lines of text in an input source should take a `Reader` parameter. If you want to count the lines of text in two files, one of which is encoded in UTF-8 and one of which is encoded in UTF-16, you'd create an `InputStreamReader` around a `FileInputStream` for each file, specifying the appropriate encoding each time.

(Personally I would avoid `FileReader` completely - the fact that it doesn't let you specify an encoding makes it useless IMO.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `FileReader` is so goddamn useless. :)

Comment: why does a `FileInputStream` interpret my simple UTF-8 encoded text the same as an `InputStreamReader` does? Is it as Peter Lawrey says - I would only notice the difference if I was to add obscure characters to my text?

Comment: @WulfgarPro : it doesn't. It reads raw bytes. If you send these raw bytes to System.out, the System.out (which is a PrintStream) outputs them to the console by using the default platform encoding.

Comment: @JB: more precisely, it outputs them to the console without any encoding, and the console hopefully is configured to use the same encoding as the "default character encoding".

Answer (score 3):

An `InputStream` reads bytes, while a `Reader` reads characters. Because of the way bytes map to characters, you need to specify the character set (or encoding) when you create an `InputStreamReader`, the default being the platform character set.

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading/writing text which contains characters which could be > 127 , use a char stream. When you are reading/writing binary data use a byte stream.

You cna read text as binary if you wish, but unless you make alot of assumptions it rarely gains you much.